# How to write short reusable functions using promises?

Tags: javascript, promise

It's easy to write reusable one-line functions in synchronous code.

Like this:

```
function bounce(password, error)
{
  if (!passwordChecker.validate(password))
  {
    console.error('bad password');
    database.logError(password);
    error.value = htmlHelper(error5);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

that you can use easily reuse everywhere like so:

```
if (bounce(password, result)) return result.value;
//else continue with the web method...
```

---

**But how on earth do you do this using asynchronous promise code?**

Is there any way to shorten this code to one line? I don't want to copy and paste 10 whole lines every time:

```
return new Promise<string>(function (resolve, reject) 
{
    const bouncerError: {value: string} = {value : null};
    self._bouncer.isTokenValid(request, bouncerError)
    .then((isValid) => 
    {
        if (!isValid) 
        {
            resolve(bouncerError.value); 
            throw null; 
        }
        return Promise.resolve();
    })
    .then(() => {
        //continue with the web method
    });
```

Here's the resuable function, if it helps clarify my thinking:

```
isTokenValid(request: hapi.Request, jsonErrorResponseString: {value: string})
{
    const self = this;
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        if (!request || !request.headers || !request.headers['token'])
        {
            jsonErrorResponseString.value = responseHelper.getErrorResponse(ResponseErrorCode.invalidToken);
            resolve(false);
            return;
        }

        self._jwtHelper.isJwtValid(request.headers['token'])
        .then(function(isValid: boolean)
        {
            if (!isValid)
            {
                jsonErrorResponseString.value = responseHelper.getErrorResponse(ResponseErrorCode.invalidToken);
                resolve(false);
            }
            resolve(true);
        }
        ,function(error: any)
        {
            jsonErrorResponseString.value = responseHelper.getErrorResponse(ResponseErrorCode.unknownError);
            resolve(false);
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: The basics are exactly the same, just the calling convention is different. Instead of  `if (bounce(password, result))` you'd do `bounce(password, result).then(/* if code */, /* else code */)`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see. I think if I pass the outer promise into common code it saves space:

```
    const isValid = await bouncer.isTokenValid(token);
    if (!isValid) throw new ControlFlowError();
```

and

```
isTokenValid(request: hapi.Request, hapiResolve: any): Promise<boolean>
{
    if (!request || !request.headers || !request.headers['token'])
    {
        hapiResolve(responseHelper.getErrorResponse(ResponseErrorCode.invalidToken));
        return Promise.resolve(false);
    }

    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject)  =>
    {
        this._jwtHelper.isJwtValid(request.headers['token'])
        .then(function(isValid: boolean)
        {
            if (!isValid)
            {
                hapiResolve(responseHelper.getErrorResponse(ResponseErrorCode.invalidToken));
                resolve(false);
            }
            resolve(true);
        }
        ,function(error: any)
        {
            hapiResolve(responseHelper.getErrorResponse(ResponseErrorCode.unknownError));
            resolve(false);
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: I would also recommend that you check out the RxJs library. It contains a lot of cool JavaScript constructs for dealing with asynchronous programming (Promises, events, etc.) very succinctly. Link:
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS

Comment: I'd just started to understand lodash and async.js and now a whole new library :-(   

These rxjs people don't really explain **why** I'd use their library over async.js: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/mapping/async/comparing.md